# Copying more than one tables from one database to another

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have 160 tables in one database. Requirement is to copy them into different database.

> Database : Oracle using TOAD tool.

Ex:

> Database A: 160 tables
>
> Database B: want to copy all 160 tables from Database A into B.

I know I can write DB link for one table coping but I want to copy all 160 tables from different database. is that possible?

Comment: are you having these two databases rely on one server or different server

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the standard **DATA PUMP** feature. You need to export all the 160 tables from source using `EXPDP` and then import them into the destination database using `IMPDP`.

See the documentation to read more about [DATA PUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_dp.htm).

I believe most of the **GUI based tools** like `TOAD`, `SQL Developer` etc. has the export and import features.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you only need the tables/data and you are not concerned about indexes and constraints, and given that you can use a DBLINK, you could use a simple script to copy all tables from the remote server to your local server:

```
BEGIN
    FOR C IN (SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES@REMOTEDB) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || C.TABLE_NAME || ' AS (SELECT * FROM ' || C.TABLE_NAME || '@REMOTEDB)';
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If this is not an option, DATA PUMP should indeed be used, as @LalitKumarB already said.